# Specific style using shader editing nodes

Tags: node-editor, shaders, procedural

I am trying to play with the shading nodes and wondering if anyone knows how I could achieve some sort of airbrushed or styled effect on my renders.

The below image is the kind of style I am after if anyone has any knowledge or insight of how I could get started I would greatly appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: Still, or animated?

Comment: Just a still image, I'm trying to achieve this saturated blurred effect.

Answer (score 4):

For the grainy effect, well actually you could use the *Cycles* render engine and keep the *Sampling* value very low, for once you'll be glad to have grains. I don't know if it's doable in the *Compositor*. You can do it with an image editor (*Filter > Other > Random Noise* in Krita for example), or fake with your materials with some *Noise* nodes, like that:

[image]

I'm not sure it was part of your question but for the smoke itself, you can create a bezier curve, bevel it, play with the vertices *Radius* and *Tilt* values (shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

Give it a mix between a *Diffuse* and *Transparent* node, use a *Noise* as factor, the *Texture Coordinate* UV output will allow you to follow the curve shape, use the *Mapping* node *Scale* values to stretch the noise along the good axis. In *Eevee* don't forget to choose *Material > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* so that the smoke is transparent:

[image]

Comment: Wow so helpful! I will defo give this a try.